# How to customize labels "Previous page" and "Next page" on Pagination Ant Design?

Tags: antd

i'm working in project React + Ant Design. The application should be translated in many languages. I use react-i18next to perform that. However, i can't figure out how to apply my translation for labels "Previous page" and "Next page" on Pagination component. For example, for french language, i want to use "Page précédente" and "Page suivante".

[image]

[image]

[image: Edit Simple pagination]

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [This](https://ant.design/docs/react/i18n) what you are looking for? The default language of is currently English. If you need to change the language you can use their Internalization. They have tons of supported languages. This provides a React Component ConfigProvider for configuring antd locale text globally.

In this example da_DK would change the language to Danish.

```
  <ConfigProvider locale={da_DK}>
    <App />
  </ConfigProvider>
```

Comment: Thank you, i've done a test with your example using fr_FR language and it works :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pagination locale object as follows:

```
<Table
    pagination={{
        locale: {
            next_page: "Page suivante",
            prev_page: "Page précédente",
        },
    }}
</
```